# Asking the user if they want to take a survey on an Android app when the user is exiting the app

Tags: android, survey

We are trying to test our alpha app with Android users.  The users will use the app and when they are done using the app we want to ask the user to take a brief survey to tell us about their app experience.

We want to ask the user if they would like to take a survey when they are exiting the Android app.  What is the best way to do this?  We read that there is no reliable way to tell on Android if the user is exiting the app.

If anyone else has done a similar exercise and have insight on what worked, that will be greatly appreciated.

Note that we will not have this survey on our production app on Android market.  We just need a way to ask the users to take a survey from the app when they are done using the app and ready to give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you let the survey pop up when the user clicks "exit" in your app or the press the back key. User do leave responses and constructive criticism on your apps Google Play page.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the back key functionality in the launcher or appropriate activity and provide user with 2 options,
1. Submit feedback
2. Later (Exit the app now)

Answer (score 0):

Don't trigger any kind of popup when they hit Back or Home (or even worse, `onPause`/`onStop`/`onDestroy`) - that is extremely bad form.  In Android, your app should never be thought of as "exited," since the user may be coming right back to it after performing some other task (answering a call, checking email, etc.).

The right thing to do here is simply have a UI element (like a button) from which the user can trigger the survey.

If you absolutely must display an unsolicited prompt, do the user a favor and note that you've prompted them and they've elected to take the survey (for instance, through `SharedPreferences`).  This way you can at least only show the prompt if they haven't taken the survey in the past.